# Bash dialog function not displaying

Tags: bash, syntax, dialog

so i'm trying to show my dialog calendar with a function , using temp file method but its not working , can you help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
PROMPT=/tmp/prompt.sh.$$
DISPLAY=/tmp/output.sh.$$
trap "rm $DISPLAY; rm $PROMPT; exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

show_calendar()
{
    --clear --backtitle "backtitle" --title "title" --calendar 0 0 
    >$DISPLAY
    dialog <$DISPLAY
}
dialog --clear \
--backtitle "backtitle" \
--title "Menu:" \
--menu "Please choose" 15 50 2 \
Calendar "Show calendar" \
Exit "Exit from shell" 2>"${PROMPT}"

select=$(<"${PROMPT}")

case $select in
    Calendar) show_calendar;;
    Exit) break;;
esac

done

[ -f $DISPLAY ] && rm $DISPLAY
[ -f $PROMPT ] && rm $PROMPT
```

Thanks

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: What is that function supposed to do?

Comment: The function is supposed to display a calendar where you can select date etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script store the name of the temp file inside the 'DISPLAY' variable. This is a poor choice, as the DISPLAY variable usually holds the connection string to the X display.

Putting the above problem to the side, the code attempt to invoke the 'dialog' program using standard input (dialog < $DISPLAY). Unfortunately, dialog only take command line parameter. Furthermore, the '--calendar' takes 3 parameters.

Consider instead

```
# No temporary file
dialog --clear --backtitle "backtitle" --title "title" --calendar 0 0
```

OR using temporary file:

```
TEMP_CMD=/tmp/output.sh.$$
echo "" --clear --backtitle "backtitle" --title "title" --calendar 0 0 > $TEMP_CMD
dialog $(<$TEMP_CMD)
```